# "Too many levels of symbolic link" when installing any IRC server

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, irc

I've been trying all morning to install *any* IRC server on my 16.04 VPS. I've had a lot of other issues, but now whenever I try to install basically any IRC server I get something like this:

```
Failed to validate path /var/run/inspircd.pid: Too many levels of symbolic                                                                                                                           links
fchownat() of /var/log/inspircd.log failed: Invalid argument
```

or

```
Failed to validate path /var/run/ircd: Too many levels of symbolic links
Failed to validate path /var/run/ngircd: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I'm not really sure where to begin troubleshooting this. I know this can happen when you create a symlink that eventually loops back to itself, but /var/run/ doesn't exist until it attempts to install the package. Unless the file being installed is a symlink pointing to an existing symlink that points back to this, I don't really know what to make of this.

Here is the full output of APT when I tried to install inspircd after a failed ngircd attempt.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient20 libpq5 libtre5 mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  mysql-server ldap-server postgresql gnutls-bin tre-agrep
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  inspircd libmysqlclient20 libpq5 libtre5 mysql-common
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 828 kB/2354 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 mysql-comm                                                                                                                          on all 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 [15.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libmysqlcl                                                                                                                          ient20 amd64 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 [813 kB]
Fetched 828 kB in 1s (445 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 42254 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient20:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient20_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb                                                                                                                           ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpq5_9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq5:amd64 (9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtre5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtre5_0.8.0-4+deb8u1build0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtre5:amd64 (0.8.0-4+deb8u1build0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package inspircd.
Preparing to unpack .../inspircd_2.0.20-5build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking inspircd (2.0.20-5build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up ngircd (22.1-2build1) ...
Failed to validate path /var/run/ircd: Too many levels of symbolic links
Failed to validate path /var/run/ngircd: Too many levels of symbolic links
Job for ngircd.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemct                                                                                                                          l status ngircd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ngircd, action "start" failed.
● ngircd.service - Next Generation IRC Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ngircd.service; enabled; vendor pres                                                                                                                          et: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2019-02-19 13:46:49 EST; 34ms                                                                                                                           ago
  Process: 5323 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ngircd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare ngircd[5324]: Not running with changed ro....
Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare ngircd[5324]: Can't change working direct...!
Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare ngircd[5324]: IO subsystem: epoll (hint s....
Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare systemd[1]: ngircd.service: PID file /var...y
Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare ngircd[5324]: Now listening on [0::]:6667....
Feb 19 13:45:19 hardwareflare ngircd[5324]: Now listening on [0.0.0.0]:....
Feb 19 13:46:49 hardwareflare systemd[1]: ngircd.service: Start operati....
Feb 19 13:46:49 hardwareflare systemd[1]: Failed to start Next Generati....
Feb 19 13:46:49 hardwareflare systemd[1]: ngircd.service: Unit entered ....
Feb 19 13:46:49 hardwareflare systemd[1]: ngircd.service: Failed with r....
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package ngircd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql                                                                                                                          /my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libpq5:amd64 (9.5.14-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
Setting up libtre5:amd64 (0.8.0-4+deb8u1build0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up inspircd (2.0.20-5build2) ...
Failed to validate path /var/run/inspircd.pid: Too many levels of symbolic                                                                                                                           links
fchownat() of /var/log/inspircd.log failed: Invalid argument
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ngircd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```